# Фон сайта не растягивается на весь экран (имеются белые полосы по всем сторонам экрана)

Tags: html, css

```css
/* Intro */
.intro {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    
    background: url("../images/intro.jpg") center no-repeat;
    -webkit-bacground-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header_inner">
            <div class="header_logo">MoGo</div>

                <nav class="nav">
                    <a class="nav_link active" href="#">About</a>
                    <a class="nav_link" href="#">Service</a>
                    <a class="nav_link" href="#">Work</a>
                    <a class="nav_link" href="#">Blog</a>
                    <a class="nav_link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="intro"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro_inner">
            <h2 class="intro_suptittle">Creative Template</h2>
            <h1 class="intro_tittle">Welcome To MoGo</h1>

            <a class="btn" href="#">Learn More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию браузер добавляет для body отступы. Попробуйте добавить себе в css. Или можно подключить файл normalize.css, он убирает всё такое.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего оно:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: а может там `border: 8px solid white;` :))

Comment: Да, видимо забыл вписать margin. Получилось, спасибо))))